# Why isn't grep agreeing with other regex tools?

Tags: linux, regex, grep, ipv4

I am currently trying to write a grep command to find IP addresses in its input. My regex is

```
\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+
```

which works as expected in [an online tester](https://regex101.com/r/zhH0rv/1) with all flavors of regex.

Yet, when I put it in a grep command (`-o` means to output the text of the matches themselves, instead of the entire line.), it gives unexpected results. For example,

```
nslookup s4.moddedminecraft.club | grep -o "\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+"
```

gives empty output. The output of the nslookup command is as follows:

```
$ nslookup s4.moddedminecraft.club
Server:     1.1.1.1
Address:    1.1.1.1#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   s4.moddedminecraft.club
Address: 46.4.20.113
```

When I put that output into the linked online tester, it behaves as expected, and matches all of the IPv4 addresses. Why does grep behave differently?

```
$ grep -V
grep (GNU grep) 3.4
Copyright (C) 2020 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <https://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>.
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Written by Mike Haertel and others; see
<https://git.sv.gnu.org/cgit/grep.git/tree/AUTHORS>.
```

Answer (score 1):

- grep uses POSIX basic regular expressions that doesn't support `\d`
- egrep uses POSIX extended regular expressions.
- php or python and many other language use PCRE.

With POSIX, you have to escape the `+` quantifier:

```
[0-9]\+\.[0-9]\+\.[0-9]\+\.[0-9]\+
```

Comment: Changing the expression to `[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+` does not fix the problem, and none of the alternatives that I know for `+` work either (e.g. `*`). EDIT: I got it working via `[0-9]\*[.][0-9]\*[.][0-9]\*`

Comment: @john01dav: escape the + `[0-9]\+\.[0-9]\+\.[0-9]\+\.[0-9]\+`

Comment: `LC_COLLATE=POSIX` will make this more POSIX. See [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/414226/108618).

Comment: iirc, POSIX Basic regexes don't support + at all, do they?